# Why set failed in CMAKE scripts

Tags: cmake

Suppose `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = C://a//b//c`, and if I run the following cmake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )
set(project_name "hello_cmake")
project(${project_name})
add_executable(hello src/main.cpp)
 if(WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install" CACHE PATH "Installation Directory" )
  else()
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local" CACHE PATH "Installation Directory")
  endif()
```

I expect `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = C://a//b//c//install` if I do not define `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` when I first call `cmake ..` from the folder `C://a//b//c`. However, it does not work in that way, and CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is given a strange folder: `C://Program Files (x86)//hello_cmake`. Any ideas?

Comment: Avoid modifying `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` by default, it's not subproject-friendly.

Comment: I agree with @ruslo, and would go further in that it's not user-friendly.  If I set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` on the command line (e.g. `cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr`) then I'd be surprised to find `make install` using /usr/local.  Setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` inside your CMakeLists.txt should probably only be done after checking it's not already set.  Or if you absolutely must set it to hard-coded paths like this, then a warning message if the user has already set it would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the recommended CMake incantation for handling `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`:

```
IF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
  SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX <path> CACHE PATH <comment> FORCE)
ENDIF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
```

Note the `FORCE` in the set.  Apparently, the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is set fairly early in the invocation of CMake, which means it will already be set in the cache by the time you get to this line.  Thus the need for FORCE.

Source is an email discussion on CMake mailing list: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-December/041135.html